# Minkowski Functional is a norm implies the underlying set is convex

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, symmetric and contain $0$. Let $\rho$ be the corresponding  Minkowski functional on $V$. Prove that if $\rho$ is a norm, then $V$ is convex.

I have shown that $V\subseteq \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : \rho (x) < 1\}$. I want to show the reverse inclusion which will prove our result. It suffices to show that $V$ is star-shaped w.r.t $0$. But I couldn't prove this fact.

Comment: One can generally prove $\{ x : \rho(x) < 1\} \subseteq V \subseteq \{ x : \rho(x) \leqslant 1\}$, without assuming that $V$ is open. $V$ being open then implies equality in the first inclusion.

Comment: I can show the 1st inclusion using convexity of $V$ , but without using convexity I am not getting it.

Comment: Grrmbll, sorry. You wrote that you need to assume star-shapedness in the question, and yet I tacitly assumed it. Without star-shapedness, this need not hold, consider e.g. $V = \{ x : \lVert x\rVert \in [0,1) \cup (2,3)\}$, where $\lVert\,\cdot\rVert$ denotes the Euclidean norm (any norm would do, actually).

Comment: Are you sure the premise is that $V$ be symmetric, and not that it be balanced?

Comment: yes, I am sure. Those are the only information that $V$ is open and symmetric containing $0$.

Comment: In that case, see the example above. It need not hold.

Comment: For that example you gave, how do you know minkowski functional on $V$ is a norm? It's given that if $\rho$ is norm, then $V$ is convex.

Comment: How do you define the Minkowski functional of $V$? As $\mu_V(x) = \inf \{ t > 0 : x \in tV\}$ or as $\inf \{ t > 0: s > t \implies x \in sV\}$? In the first case, for the example we have $\mu_V = \frac{1}{3}\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$, and in the latter case $\mu_V = \lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$. In either case, we have a norm. If you have some other definition of the Minkowski functional, which?

Comment: Thanks. I am using  the first one as definition of minkowski functional. I need to assume that $V$ is balanced to show that it is convex.

Comment: And then it is a fortiori star-shaped.